# Parsing Json in iOS without keys common

Tags: ios, json, parsing

My JSON String is :

```
[
    {'Local':'webaddress'},
    {'QA':'webaddress1'}
]
```

My Code is :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dataDictonary = [NSJSONSerialization
                                       JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                       options:0
                                       error:nil];


        NSArray *keys = [dataDictonary allKeys];
        NSArray *values = [dataDictonary allValues];
        int i=0;
        NSLog(@"",[keys count]);
        NSLog(@"",[values count]);
        int i=0;
        for ( NSString *items in keys )
        {
            NSLog(@"----");
            NSLog(@"Name: %@", items);
            NSLog(@"Address: %@", values[i++]);
            NSLog(@"----");
        }
```

Here i get size as nothing blank in NSlog and can't Parse this value don't don't why. Please help..

Comment: Your JSON is not a dictionary, but an array with two items, each item a dictionary with a single key. [] in JSON means an array. {} in JSON means a dictionary.

Comment: Moreover `NSLog(@"",[keys count]);` can't work, you should at least write `NSLog(@"%i",[keys count]);` and you'd see you have zero keys and zero values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is an Array with Objects inside so you need to convert it to a NSArray:

```
NSString *json_string = @"[{\"Local\": \"webaddress\" }, {\"QA\": \"webaddress1\" }]";
NSError *error;
NSArray *JSON =
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [json_string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                  error: &error];

NSLog(@"Local: %@", JSON[0][@"Local"]); // output is: Local: webaddress
```

**UPDATE**

```
// itherate through array
for(NSDictionary *dictionary in JSON)
{
    //now you can iterate throug each dicitonary
    NSEnumerator *enumerator = [dictionary keyEnumerator];
    id key;

    while((key = [enumerator nextObject])){
        NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [dictionary objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

**Log looks like this:**

key=Local value=webaddress

key=QA value=webaddress1

Comment: But 'Local' 'QA' this values won't be fixed than how to access it JSON[0][0] ? But its giving null.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works fine. Actually the problem was with the response, the json keys with '' was not able to parse if i provide "" than it will parse. I was not aware about it.